# How to redirect homepage with Cpanel file manager?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

My current homepage is `example.com.sg`.

Can I redirect `example.com.sg` to `example.com.sg/test` using the Cpanel file manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a redirect, follow these steps:

1. In the Domains section of the cPanel home screen, click **Redirects**.
2. Under **Add Redirect**, select the redirection type.

> To specify a permanent redirection, select **Permanent (301)**. To specify
> a temporary redirection, select **Temporary (302)**. 301 and 302 refer to
> the HTTP status codes that the server sends to a web browser.

3. Select the domain, and then type the web page that you want to redirect.
4. In the **redirects to** text box, type the destination web page.

> You can redirect the web page to another web page on your web site,
> or to a web page on a completely different web site.

5. Click **Add**.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out